# Xamarin android Could not receive the push notification on OnMessageReceived while swipe away app

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

When app is in foreground (visible on screen)/background (minimize the app) function OnMessageReceived is called and notification message is displayed as expected. When I swipe of the app or click close all then I am not getting the notification message, While I am getting notification for other commercial app if I close also.. **I am using Data only message**

I am using nuget Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging ,

**Android manifest**

```
<application android:label="MyTestingApp" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

**MyMessagingService extending FirebaseMessagingService**

```
[Service(Exported = false, Enabled = true, DirectBootAware =true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService{

}
```

**MainActivity--> OnStart()**

```
const int requestLocationId = 0;

string[] notiPermission =
{
    Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications
};

string[] wakePermission =
{
    Manifest.Permission.WakeLock
};

if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 33) return;

if (activity.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications) != Permission.Granted)
{
    activity.RequestPermissions(notiPermission, requestLocationId);
    activity.RequestPermissions(wakePermission, requestLocationId);
}
```

I have created the apk file with Sigin Identity and installed in Samsung S23. Tested with API call (Legacy) using postmen. I am getting the success reponse but app is not displaying anything. After open the app also not receiving any notification message.

**postMan Body**

```
{
    "to": "dpm-g36NSEaC5XFadT3ZnY:APA91bEIarlCxz6UEpyY7CYeBsnCSBpXApW6gHEOiVrvk0URkRP4FCqAHmApPFH4KQLDMfYhkkOTTUZ7ZEsRlyKzCPPS9CuLtet9pXi8_DUflE6h_g-iqtD_9DcVQ4amyb1CCfW05vN2",
    "CollapseKey": "1",    
    "data": {
        "body": "Hello,Good Morning! . Have a gr8 day ahead! message_web",
        "title": "Good Morning!)",
        "image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2055100/pexels-photo-2055100.jpeg",
        "notificationSmallIcon": "macrokiosk.boldwallet.drawable.logo",
        "notificationSmallIconColor": "#00ff00",
        "notificationLargeIcon" : "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1352603244/photo/shot-of-an-unrecognizable-businessman-working-on-his-laptop-in-the-office.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=mTABddPRSU1r_hCBpknMjJbCIrJAicjjXGSU42rx-YI=",
        "click_action": "web",
        "actionResult": "https://google.com/"
    }
}
```

**Additional info**

*Google Play Services Version*

118.2.0.5

*dependencies/Packages*

```
Xamarin.AndroidX.Core 1.12.0.4
Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common 2.7.0.1
Xamarin.Essentials 1.7.3
Xamarin.CommunityToolkit 2.0.2
Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 123.3.1.1
Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2478
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 118.0.1
```

Solution for : When we swipe the app to close need to receive the notification

Comment: You can try to update your all nugets to the latest version and try again. If the problem persists, then try to reopen your app and close again for notifications to work.

Comment: Still issue exists. I am receiving notification handled by the system tray even send data message